# Video Streaming App using FastAPI and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, streaming, fastapi

I am trying to render an `HTML` page that shows video streaming from a webcam. However, I am facing the following error:

```py
500 Server Error TypeError: TemplateResponse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

**My FastAPI app:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import cv2

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/")
async def index():
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html")


async def gen_frames(camera_id):
    cap=  cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        # for cap in caps:
        # # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = cap.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  
    
   if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,  host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

**My HTML Page (index.html):**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Multiple Live Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Multiple Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed', id='0') }}" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Traceback:**

[image: Error capture]

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass a Request when you are working with templates.

```
from fastapi import Request

@app.get("/")
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

So you can also serve your video as another path, with [**StreamingResponse**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse)

```
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse


@app.get("/serve/{camera_id}", include_in_schema=False)
async def serve_video(camera_id: int):
    return StreamingResponse(gen_frames(camera_id))
```

Then fetch that response with Ajax or Axios etc.

Comment: after adding this i am getting this error:- `500 Server Error NoMatchFound:  in url_path_for
    raise NoMatchFound()
starlette.routing.NoMatchFound`

Comment: @Swaraj is it just this? share the full message, also make sure your template name is matching

Comment: I guess this line causing error:- `<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed', id='0') }}" width="100%">`  Any idea what mistake i have done?

Comment: So in FastAPI(actually Starlette) you can use `url_for` to serve static files, i think it 'd be better to use Streaming Response. If it's okay for you i can update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220728/discussion-between-swaraj-and-yagizcan-degirmenci).

Answer (score 5):

When using [`Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/), you need to declare a `Request` parameter in the endpoint that will return a template, as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Below are given two options (with complete code samples) on how to stream (live) video using FastAPI and [`OpenCV`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/). **Option 1** demonstrates an approach based on your question using the `HTTP` protocol and FastAPI/Starlette's [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse). **Option 2** uses the [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) protocol, which can easily handle HD video streaming and is supported by FastAPI/Starlette (documentation can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) and [here](https://www.starlette.io/websockets/))

I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to better understand `async`/`await` in Python, and FastAPI in particular, as well as when to define an endpoint in FastAPI with `async def` or normal `def`. For instance, the functions of `cv2` library, such as `camera.read()` and `cv2.imencode()`, are *synchronous* blocking (either IO-bound or CPU-bound) functions, which means that, when called, they would block the event loop until they complete. That is the reason that both the `StreamingResponse`'s generator (i.e., the `gen_frames()` function) and the `video_feed` endpoint in Option 1 are defined with normal `def`, as this would cause any requests to that endpoint to be run in an external threadpool that would be then `await`ed (hence, FastAPI will still work *asynchronously*). It should be noted though that, in the case of `StreamingResponse`, even if one defined the `video_feed` endpoint with `async def` and the `StreamingResponse`'s generator with normal `def` (as it contains blocking operations), FastAPI/Starlette, in order to prevent the event loop from getting blocked, would use [`iterate_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/3734e85c187a22e30c5ba3530a4f4506912f8eec/starlette/concurrency.py#L57) to run the generator in a separate thread that would be then `await`ed—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) for more details and the relevant source code. Hence, any requests to that `async def` endpoint would not block the event loop because of some blocking `StreamingResponse` generator. **Note:** Avoid defining the generator with `async def`, if it contains blocking operations, as FastAPI/Starlette would then run it in the event loop, instead of a separate thread. Only define it with `async def`, when you are certain that there is no *synchronous* operation inside that would block the event loop and/or when need to `await` for coroutines/`async` functions. In Option 2, the `get_stream` endpoint had to be defined with `async def`, as FastAPI/Starlette's `websockets` functions are `async` functions and need to be `await`ed. In this case, the `cv2` blocking functions will block the event loop every time they get called, until they complete (which may or may not be trivial, given the time taken to complete those operations, as well as the needs/requirements of one's application; for instance, whether the application is expected to serve multiple requests/users at the same time). However, one could still run blocking operations, such as `cv2`'s functions, inside `async def` endpoints without blocking the event loop, as well as having multiple instances (workers/processes) of the application running at the same time. Please take a look at the linked answer above for more details and solutions on this subject.

### Option 1 - Using `HTTP` Protocol

You can access the live streaming at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

**app.py**

```py
import cv2
import time
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse


app = FastAPI()
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        time.sleep(0.03)


@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.get('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return StreamingResponse(gen_frames(), media_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3> Live Streaming </h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="50%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Option 2 - Using `WebSocket` Protocol

You can access the live streaming at http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Related answers using the `WebSocket` protocol can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415451/17865804).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import uvicorn
import asyncio
import cv2


app = FastAPI()
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get('/')
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def get_stream(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            success, frame = camera.read()
            if not success:
                break
            else:
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                await websocket.send_bytes(buffer.tobytes()) 
            await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        print("Client disconnected")   

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

Below is the `HTML` template for establishing the `WebSocket` connection, receiving the image bytes and creating a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) URL (which is released after the image is loaded, so that the object will subsequently be garbage collected, rather being kept in memory, unnecessarily), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804), to display the video frame in the browser.

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Live Streaming</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="frame" src="">
        <script>
            let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            let image = document.getElementById("frame");
            image.onload = function(){
                URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); // release the blob URL once the image is loaded
            } 
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is also a Python client based on the [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) library and [`OpenCV`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), which you may use to connect to the server, in order to receive and display the video frames in a Python app.

**client.py**

```py
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import websockets
import numpy as np
import asyncio
import cv2


async def main():
    url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws'
    
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(url):
        try:
             #count = 1
             while True:
                contents = await websocket.recv()
                arr = np.frombuffer(contents, np.uint8)
                frame = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
                
                #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
                #count += 1
        except ConnectionClosed:
            continue  # attempt reconnecting to the server (otherwise, call break)


asyncio.run(main())
```