# FastAPI StreamingResponse not streaming with generator function

Tags: python, python-requests, streaming, fastapi, openai-api

I have a relatively simple FastAPI app that accepts a query and streams back the response from ChatGPT's API. ChatGPT is streaming back the result and I can see this being printed to console as it comes in.

What's not working is the `StreamingResponse` back via FastAPI. The response gets sent all together instead. I'm really at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Here is the FastAPI app code:

```py
import os
import time

import openai

import fastapi
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status, Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

auth_scheme = HTTPBearer()
app = fastapi.FastAPI()

openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]


def ask_statesman(query: str):
    #prompt = router(query)
    
    completion_reason = None
    response = ""
    while not completion_reason or completion_reason == "length":
        openai_stream = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": query}],
            temperature=0.0,
            stream=True,
        )
        for line in openai_stream:
            completion_reason = line["choices"][0]["finish_reason"]
            if "content" in line["choices"][0].delta:
                current_response = line["choices"][0].delta.content
                print(current_response)
                yield current_response
                time.sleep(0.25)


@app.post("/")
async def request_handler(auth_key: str, query: str):
    if auth_key != "123":
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": auth_scheme.scheme_name},
        )
    else:
        stream_response = ask_statesman(query)
        return StreamingResponse(stream_response, media_type="text/plain")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True, log_level="debug")
```

And here is the very simple `test.py` file to test this:

```py
import requests

query = "How tall is the Eiffel tower?"
url = "http://localhost:8000"
params = {"auth_key": "123", "query": query}

response = requests.post(url, params=params, stream=True)

for chunk in response.iter_lines():
    if chunk:
        print(chunk.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First, it wouldn't be good practice to use a [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request for requesting data from the server. Using a [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request instead would be more suitable to your case. In addition to that, you shouldn't be sending credentials, such as `auth_key` as part of the URL (i.e., using the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)), but you should rather use [`Headers`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/header-params/) and/or [`Cookies`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cookie-params/) (using [`HTTPS`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/)). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details and examples on the concepts of headers and cookies, as well as the risks involved when using query parameters instead. Helpful posts around this topic can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268404/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74088523/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70702903/17865804).

Second, if you are executing a blocking operation (i.e., blocking I/O-bound or CPU-bound tasks) inside the [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse)'s generator function, you should define the generator function with `def` instead of `async def`, as, otherwise, the blocking operation, as well as the `time.sleep()` function that is used inside your generator, would blcok the event loop. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804), if the function for streaming the response body is a normal `def` generator and not an `async def` one, FastAPI will use [`iterate_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/concurrency.py#L58) to run the iterator/generator in a separate thread that is then `await`ed—see `StreamingResponse`'s [relevant source code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/3734e85c187a22e30c5ba3530a4f4506912f8eec/starlette/responses.py#L226). If you prefer using an `async def` generator, then make sure to execute any blocking operations in an external `ThreadPool` (or `ProcessPool`) and `await` it, as well as use `await asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`, in cased you need to add delay in the execution of an operation. Have a look at this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details and examples.

Third, you are using `requests`' [`iter_lines()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_lines) function, which iterates over the response data, **one line at a time**. If, however, the response data did not include any line break character (i.e., `\n`), you wouldn't see the data on client's console getting printed as they arrive, until the entire response is received by the client and printed as a whole. In that case, you should instead use [`iter_content()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) and specify the `chunk_size` as desired (both cases are demonstrated in the example below).

Finally, if you would like the `StreamingResponse` to work in every browser (including Chrome as well)—in the sense of being able to see the data as they stream in—you should specify the `media_type` to a different type than `text/plain` (e.g., `application/json` or `text/event-stream`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75837557/17865804)), or **disable [MIME Sniffing](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/)**. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089065), browsers will start buffering `text/plain` responses for a certain amount (around 1445 bytes, as documented [here](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#reading-the-resource-header)), in order to check whether or not the content received is actually plain text. To avoid that, you can either set the `media_type` to `text/event-stream` (used for [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)), or keep using `text/plain`, but set the [`X-Content-Type-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) response header to `nosniff`, which would disable MIME Sniffing (both options are demonstrated in the example below).

## Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import asyncio


app = FastAPI()


async def fake_data_streamer():
    for i in range(10):
        yield b'some fake data\n\n'
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


# If your generator contains blocking operations such as time.sleep(),
# then define the generator function with normal `def`. Otherwise, use `async def`, 
# but run any blocking operations in an external ThreadPool, etc. (see 2nd paragraph of this answer)
'''
import time

def fake_data_streamer():
    for i in range(10):
        yield b'some fake data\n\n'
        time.sleep(0.5)
'''        

    
@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return StreamingResponse(fake_data_streamer(), media_type='text/event-stream')
    # or, use:
    '''
    headers = {'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'}
    return StreamingResponse(fake_data_streamer(), headers=headers, media_type='text/plain')
    '''
```

**test.py** (using Python `requests`)

```py
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/"

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):  # or, for line in r.iter_lines():
        print(chunk)
```

**test.py** (using [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/)—see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) for the benefits of using `httpx` over `requests`)

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

with httpx.stream('GET', url) as r:
    for chunk in r.iter_raw():  # or, for line in r.iter_lines():
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer. Anyone looking at this later should follow the recommendations Chris gives.

Also, I should note that my original code actually worked (although with some issues, as Chris described). There was some issue with iter_lines and my test file, but I got this sorted. The root issue stemmed from an issue with a serverless provider I was using to host this app.

Comment: @Chris also a big thanks from my side, but what I quite don´t get is whether a request (assuming it´s net I/O) that being made inside the StreamingResponse should use an async def generator? From my understanding of those links is that it should be done via an async request, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Bennimi If you are using a library that performs blocking I/O-bound operations, such as `requests`, it might be best to use a `def` generator, as explained in the 2nd paragraph of the answer above (as well as the references included). I would, though, suggest defining the generator with `async def` and use a library that provides `async` API, such as `httpx` - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804)

Answer (score 3):

If you opt to use Langchain to interact with OpenAI (which I highly recommend), it provides stream method, which effectively returns a generator.

Slight modification to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17865804/chris)' code above,

### `api.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from langchain.llms import OpenAI


llm = OpenAI(
    streaming=True,
    verbose=True,
    temperature=0,
)

app = FastAPI()


def chat_gpt_streamer(query: str):
    for resp in llm.stream(query):
        yield resp["choices"][0]["text"]


@app.get('/streaming/ask')
async def main(query: str):
    return StreamingResponse(chat_gpt_streamer(query), media_type='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="debug")
```

Similarly you can test with httpx, or requests (again copy paste from Chris' code):

### `test.py`

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/streaming/ask?query=How are you, write in 10 sentences'
with httpx.stream('GET', url) as r:
    for chunk in r.iter_raw():  # or, for line in r.iter_lines():
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While your answer works, I fail to see the advantages of LangChain. At best, it reduces code, but at the expense of flexibility. I'm actually using LangChain elsewhere in this app but only as it is useful.

Comment: You have a point, using langchain is not a big win in this case, but just wanted to highlight `llm.stream()` returning a generator is useful. Though not difficult to implement it with basic OpenAI sdk

Comment: this answer is helping me so much, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

might consider looking into Server Send Events: https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette

first install the library : `pip install sse-starlette`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse
import time


app = FastAPI()


def data_streamer():
    for i in range(10):
        yield f"_{i}_".encode("utf-8")
        time.sleep(1)


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return EventSourceResponse(data_streamer(), media_type='text/event-stream')
```

Comment: I in fact am! I'm using Modal Endpoints and it works great. modal.com

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

- In the `ask_statesman` function, change the `yield current_response`
  statement to yield `{"data": current_response}`. This will wrap each
  response line in a dictionary with a `"data"` key.
- In the `request_handler` function, instead of returning the `stream_response` directly, return a generator expression that yields each response line from `ask_statesman` wrapped in a dictionary as shown above.
  Here's the modified code:

```
import os
import time

import openai

import fastapi
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status, Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

auth_scheme = HTTPBearer()
app = fastapi.FastAPI()

openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]


def ask_statesman(query: str):
    #prompt = router(query)
    
    completion_reason = None
    response = ""
    while not completion_reason or completion_reason == "length":
        openai_stream = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": query}],
            temperature=0.0,
            stream=True,
        )
        for line in openai_stream:
            completion_reason = line["choices"][0]["finish_reason"]
            if "content" in line["choices"][0].delta:
                current_response = line["choices"][0].delta.content
                print(current_response)
                yield {"data": current_response}
                time.sleep(0.25)


@app.post("/")
async def request_handler(auth_key: str, query: str):
    if auth_key != "123":
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": auth_scheme.scheme_name},
        )
    else:
        return StreamingResponse((line for line in ask_statesman(query)), media_type="text/plain")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True, log_level="debug")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tried variations as well (returning a dict only, doing both your suggestions and the generator in a generator). None of these worked. 

It's possible it's my testing code, I may try to test this in JS.

Answer (score 1):

If testing with `curl` make sure to use the `-N` flag so that it doesn't buffer your response

Testing [ollama within a docker container](https://github.com/jmorganca/ollama/blob/main/docs/api.md) I found that the following command holds the response stream until a line break, or the response is complete, before printing to stdout

```bash
curl -X POST "http://localhost:12345/api/generate" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"model": "wizard-vicuna-uncensored", "prompt": "why is the sky blue? be verbose"}'
```

This command gives the desired typerwriter UX

```bash
curl -N -X POST "http://localhost:12345/api/generate" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"model": "wizard-vicuna-uncensored", "prompt": "why is the sky blue? be verbose"}'
```

Additional technical details can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238626/curl-structuring-request-to-validate-server-sent-events)