# FastAPI with LangChain: 'invoke' Route Returns Empty Output, While Streaming Works

Tags: fastapi, langchain

I'm building a very simple LangChain application that takes as an input a customer feedback string and categorizes it into the following pydantic class:

```
class AnalysisAttributes(BaseModel):
    overall_positive: bool = Field(description="<sentiment is positive overall>")
    mentions_pricing: bool = Field(description="<pricing is mentioned>")
    mentions_competition: bool = Field(description="<competition is mentioned>")

parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=AnalysisAttributes)
```

Here's how this should work, and it does:

```
full_pipeline = prompt | model | parser

output = full_pipeline.invoke({"feedback": "This bad company is very expensive."})

expected_output = AnalysisAttributes(overall_positive=False, mentions_pricing=True, mentions_competition=False)
assert output == expected_output.  # this works! :)
```

This works very well, all good so far! Let's serve it:

```
app = FastAPI(
  title="LangChain Server",
  version="1.0",
  description="A simple api server using Langchain's Runnable interfaces",
)

pipeline = prompt | model | parser
add_routes(app, pipeline, path="/categorize_feedback")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Now comes the strange part, check this out. On the client side, streaming works:

```
response = requests.post(
    "http://localhost:8000/categorize_feedback/stream/",
    json={'input': {'feedback': 'Prices are too high.'}}
)
for chunk in response:
    print(chunk.decode())

# event: metadata [...] data: {"overall_positive":false, ...
```

But the regular invoke does not work, it delivers an empty output:

```
response = requests.post(
    "http://localhost:8000/categorize_feedback/invoke/",
    json={'input': {'feedback': 'Prices are too high.'}}
)
print(response.json())

# {'output': {}, 'callback_events': [], 'metadata': {'run_id': 'acdd089d-3c80-4624-8122-17c4173dc1ec'}}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is the output parser, as if I remove it from the chain, everything works perfectly fine, the invoke as well.

EDIT:

Currently using a workaround using FastAPI directly:

```
@app.post('/categorize_feedback')
async def categorize_feedback(input_data: FeedbackInput) -> AnalysisAttributes:
    full_pipeline = prompt | model | parser
    output = full_pipeline.invoke(input_data.model_dump())
    return output
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the problem of parser. More than a problem of generation method. Stream returns one by one, but invoke returns when all inference finished.

Comment: Yea, it seems like the result of the full_pipeline.invoke() is not returned correctly. See edit.