# Is it possible to implement a stream fastapi response with async callback io function?

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi

Say, I have a method from third-party library, which receive a callback, start a thread, periodically send some data using that callback, then stop the thread.

Now I want to implement a server sent-event protocol using fastapi and sse-starelle. I have been thinking using asyncio. But since I have no way to know when the sending is done. How can I use asyncio in that situation?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) answer your question?