# Streaming local LLM with FastAPI, Llama.cpp and Langchain

Tags: python, fastapi, langchain, llamacpp

I have setup FastAPI with Llama.cpp and Langchain. Now I want to enable streaming in the FastAPI responses. Streaming works with Llama.cpp in my terminal, but I wasn't able to implement it with a FastAPI response.

Most tutorials focused on enabling streaming with an OpenAI model, but I am using a local LLM (quantized Mistral) with llama.cpp. I think I have to modify the Callbackhandler, but no tutorial worked. Here is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
import copy
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

model_path = "../modelle/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q5_K_M.gguf"

prompt= """
<s> [INST] Im folgenden bekommst du eine Aufgabe. Erledige diese anhand des User Inputs.

### Hier die Aufgabe: ###
{typescript_string}

### Hier der User Input: ###
{input}

Antwort: [/INST]
"""

def model_response_prompt():
    return PromptTemplate(template=prompt, input_variables=['input', 'typescript_string'])

def build_llm(model_path, callback=None):
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
        #callback_manager = CallbackManager(callback)
        
        n_gpu_layers = 1 # Metal set to 1 is enough. # ausprobiert mit mehreren
        n_batch = 512#1024 # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of RAM of your Apple Silicon Chip.
   
        llm = LlamaCpp(
                max_tokens =1000,
                n_threads = 6,
                model_path=model_path,
                temperature= 0.8,
                f16_kv=True,
                n_ctx=28000, 
                n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
                n_batch=n_batch,
                callback_manager=callback_manager, 
                verbose=True,
                top_p=0.75,
                top_k=40,
                repeat_penalty = 1.1,
                streaming=True,
                model_kwargs={
                        'mirostat': 2,
                },
        )
        
        return llm

# caching LLM
@lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def get_cached_llm():
        chat = build_llm(model_path)
        return chat

chat = get_cached_llm()

app = FastAPI(
    title="Inference API for Mistral and Mixtral",
    description="A simple API that use Mistral or Mixtral",
    version="1.0",
)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

def bullet_point_model():          
    llm = build_llm(model_path=model_path)
    llm_chain = LLMChain(
        llm=llm,
        prompt=model_response_prompt(),
        verbose=True,
    )
    return llm_chain

@app.get('/model_response')
async def model(question : str, prompt: str):
    model = bullet_point_model()
    res = model({"typescript_string": prompt, "input": question})
    result = copy.deepcopy(res)
    return result
```

In a example notebook, I am calling FastAPI like this:

```
import  subprocess
import urllib.parse
import shlex
query = input("Insert your bullet points here: ")
task = input("Insert the task here: ")
#Safe Encode url string
encodedquery =  urllib.parse.quote(query)
encodedtask =  urllib.parse.quote(task)
#Join the curl command textx
command = f"curl -X 'GET' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/model_response?question={encodedquery}&prompt={encodedtask}' -H 'accept: application/json'"
print(command)
args = shlex.split(command)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

So with this code, getting responses from the API works. But I only see streaming in my terminal (I think this is because of the `StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler`. After the streaming in the terminal is complete, I am getting my FastAPI response.

What do I have to change now that I can stream token by token with FastAPI and a local llama.cpp model?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: will have a look, thanks!

Comment: On a side note, I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), as they would help you understand how to initialise an object at the application's startup and reuse it in every endpoint, as well as when to define an API endpoint with normal `def` or `async def`.

Comment: tried to follow these answers but got stuck, so any help would be appreciated!