# SSE communication using FastAPI and aiohttp does not work well

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, server-sent-events, aiohttp

server:

```
@app.get("/trader/MacroSSE")
async def trader_MacroSSE(item: traderlib.data_class.GeneralItem):
    accesskey_name = accesskey_chack(item)
    logger.info(f"accesskey_name: {accesskey_name}, item: {item}")

    return StreamingResponse(traderlib.MacroSSE().messages_generator(item), media_type="text/event-stream")
```

traderlib.MacroSSE().messages_generator(item):

```
    async def messages_generator(self,request):
        self.accesskey = request["accesskey"]
        logging.info(f"accesskey: {self.accesskey}")
        yield f"data: {self.accesskey} is connected" + "\n\n"
        while True:
            current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").encode('utf-8')
            message = {"event": "time_data", "data": current_time}
            logging.info(f"accesskey: {self.accesskey}, message: {message}")
            yield "data: "+str(message)+"\n\n"
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Client:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

start_data = {
    "accesskey": "*****"
}


async def sse_client(url, retry_interval=5):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            try:
                async with session.get(url, json=start_data) as response:
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    print(response)

                    async for line in response.content:
                        print(line)

            except (
                aiohttp.ClientError,
                aiohttp.http_exceptions.HttpProcessingError,
            ) as e:
                print(f"Network error: {e}")
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print("Timeout error")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")

            print(f"Reconnecting in {retry_interval} seconds...")
            await asyncio.sleep(retry_interval)


url = "*****"
asyncio.run(sse_client(url))
```

The code for the server and client was written as follows.
When a client makes a request to the server, the following information is returned, but the connection is immediately terminated.

```
<ClientResponse(*****) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Server': 'openresty', 'Date': 'Wed, 24 Jan 2024 12:36:58 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8', ' Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Served-By': '*****')>
```

How do I receive continuous data from the server?

I don't see any other errors in my server's logs and the connection closes right away.

```
[2024-01-24 21:37:03,961][root][INFO|whitelist_chack():66] >> request_host: localhost_2, * * * * *, request_url: * * * * *
[2024-01-24 21:37:03,963][root][INFO|trader_MacroSSE():175] >> accesskey_name: coder, item: accesskey='* * * * *'
[2024-01-24 21:37:03,965][root][INFO|whitelist_chack():70] >> working time: 0.0042 second
```

There were no errors in the client either.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: I've not checked the server code (as I generally use aiohttp for this), but in the client code you're doing a regular GET request. aiohttp doesn't directly support SSE, but it looks like there is aiohttp-sse-client2 and aiosseclient built on top of it. Maybe if someone wants to try and merge those features into aiohttp, we can support it directly (though the feature doesn't appear to have been requested before).

Comment: Does this mean that since aiohttp does not directly support SSE, it would be advisable to use aiohttp-sse-client2 or aiosseclient instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone facing to similar problem as me. This is the only problem I can find which is the most closing to my situation, so I write so extra info here and hope that it helps another one who looks for this.

---

I was stuck with the sse problem with fastAPI before and finally get a perfect solution. There are mainly 2 causes resulting this:

1. fastapi's stream response works badly in some unknonw reason.
   Solution: Use `EventSourceResponse` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75909687/21265332
2. aiohttp doesnt support sse response's prasing. Currently those opensource modules for aio's sse has mainly 2 problems:

   - Raising err in methods apart from 'GET'： Its becuz traditionally saying SSE only supports GET, but the truth is that you can response SSE with any method type. This will be very helpful for using "POST" instead of "GET" in some stream cases, especially for ppl like me builing own LLM AI service with FastAPI.
   - Prasing skips single `\n`: actually the best way is to escape `\n` with `\\n` before your yield. But sometimes you will still like to receive single line break so as to make frontend more easy to handle.

To solve the client side problem, I have done a pip module `aiossechat` which is modify from another package, so as to prase sse with aiohttp correctly. For ppl who finding this, plz just simply call `pip install aiossechat`.